# Differentiate between Button pressed and dragging in Qt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

According to the [drag and drop documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html), I was able to implement the drag functionality on my QToolButton, but that is overriding standard button click behaviour and I am unable to check if the button was pressed or there was an intent to start a drag by dragging mouse.
Here is my QToolBar..

```py
class toolbarButton(QToolButton):
    
    def __init__(self, parent = None, item = None):
        super(toolbarButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setIcon(...)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.dragStartPosition = 0
        ...

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.dragStartPosition = event.pos()
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not (event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton):
            return
        if (event.pos() - self.dragStartPosition).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return
        
        drag = QDrag(self)
        mimeData = QMimeData()
        ...
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.exec(Qt.CopyAction)
        
    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSizeHint()
    
    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(30, 30)
```

My initial thought, was to add the emit when the distance is less than startdragdistance but that would be incorrect as it would fire everytime I moved my mouse. Is there a way of achieving this in PyQt5? That I get standard QToolButton behaviour on button press and my custom behaviour on button drag?

Comment: try add `super().mousePressEvent(event)` before `if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:`

Comment: Oh wow... yeah that worked! Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override a method you are removing the default behavior, so that does not happen then you must call the parent method through super():

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    super().mousePressEvent(event)
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.dragStartPosition = event.pos()
```